# paper-dropdown-menu добавить ссылки

Tags: menu, dropdown

Помогите с выпадающим меню, не знаю как сделать выпадающие меню с сылками.

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Выберите категорию">
    <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" selected="0">
      <paper-item value="href="/indoor-lighting"">Внутреннее освещение</paper-item>
      <paper-item value="href="/outdoor-lighting"">Внешнее освещение</paper-item>
      <paper-item value="href="/new"">Новинки</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Не знаю какую функцию прописывать... В js новичок... Нужно чтобы при клике на один из пунктов меню, переходило по ссылке, указанной в value="" Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Смотри несколько вариантов легче будет через a href а если через js jquery то нужно каждый paper item написать свой класс например для первого напишите

```
class="indoor-lighting"
```

js код

```
$('.indoor-lighting').click(function () {
    window.open("ссылка на файл","_self");
})
```

Ещё подключите jquery и все.